How to extract common fields from two JSON objects and add to third JSON object
Request:
{
  "request1": {
    "MId": "1006995",
    "id": "1001",
    "MaskedFlg": true
  },
  "request2": {
    "MaskedFlg": false,
    "id": "1002",
    "MId": "",
    "AccType": "Desi"
  }
}

Expected Response:
{
  "MaskedFlg": false,
  "id": "1002",
  "MId": ""
}

I want to extract fields from request2 which are there in request1 to form the response. The request1 and request2 can have different fields each time.

To achieve this, you need to extract the fields from request2 that are also present in request1 and form the response accordingly. Below is an example of how you can accomplish this:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "request2": {
        "*": {
          "@2,request1": {
            "*": {
              "@3,&": "&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=firstElement(@0)"
    }
  }
]

In this code, we:
Iterate through the keys of request2.
Check if each key is present in request1.
If the key is present in request1, we add it to the response dictionary with its corresponding value from request2.
This way, the response only contains the fields from request2 that are also in request1, resulting in the desired output.
I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.
